# Apply Filter to Search Button in MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm having trouble getting this code to work.  I have a blank form with a simple multi-select list box (*GroupList*) and a button underneath it (*cmdSearch*).  I'm trying to put code into the button to pull select names from *GroupList* and display *Group Affiliation* names (field: `[Group Affiliations]` from table `Group_Affiliations`.

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strSearch As String
Dim Task As String

For Each varItem In Me!GroupList.ItemsSelected
strSearch = strSearch & "," & Me!GroupList.ItemData(varItem)
Next varItem
MsgBox (strSearch)
If Len(strSearch) = 0 Then
  Task = "select * from Group_Affiliations"
Else
  strSearch = Right(strSearch, Len(strSearch) - 1)
  Task = "select * from Group_Affiliations where ([Group Affiliations] in (" & strSearch & "))"
End If
DoCmd.ApplyFilter Task
End Sub
```

Please help.  I think I'm close but it wants me to set a parameter and then I receive the error:

> Error code 2501

Comment: Is `[Group Affiliations]` a text field?  If so you'd need to add apostrophes before and after each string within your `IN` statement.  E.g. `strSearch=strSearch & ",'" & Me!GroupList.ItemData(varitem) & "'"`

Comment: Ryan, thank you!  You're the best!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will likely get the results you want using the following code:

```
'Set strSearch to empty string
strSearch = ""

'Loop through as you did applying proper single quotes between items
For Each varItem In Me!GroupList.ItemsSelected
    strSearch = strSearch & "'" & Me!GroupList.ItemData(varItem) & "',"
Next varItem

'MsgBox (strSearch) 'commented out as I'm sure this is for your testing

'checking if blank (as you did)
If Len(strSearch) = 0 Then
   Task = "select * from Group_Affiliations"

'removing end comma and writing SQL statement
Else
   strSearch = Left(strSearch, Len(strSearch) - 1)
   Task = "select * from Group_Affiliations where ([Group Affiliations] in (" & strSearch & "))"
End If

DoCmd.ApplyFilter Task
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect `Task`, you will see that the elements of the `IN(...` part are not quoted. As they are strings (both in VB *and* for the database, a text field), you must quote the components:

```
strSearch = strSearch & "'" & Me!GroupList.ItemData(varItem) & "',"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked.  Thanks billyhoes and everyone!  I did show the msgbox because, in this case, I do need viewers to see what they're searching.

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
strSearch = ""
For Each varItem In Me!GroupList.ItemsSelected
strSearch = strSearch & "'" & Me!GroupList.ItemData(varItem) & "',"
Next varItem
MsgBox (strSearch)
If Len(strSearch) = 0 Then
Task = "select * from Group_Affiliations"

Else
strSearch = Left(strSearch, Len(strSearch) - 1)
Task = "select * from Group_Affiliations where ([Group Affiliations] in (" & strSearch & "))"
End If

DoCmd.ApplyFilter Task

End Sub
```